# How do I use text-right in bootstrap without having it display all the way to the right when the controls begin to stack

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-modal

`enter code here`I am pretty new to bootstrap and coding in general, so please don't blister me for this question.  I am trying to create a form that is aligned down the middle of the page.  I am able to move the label text to the right by using text-right [label][control], but when I start to narrow the page it does not stack the way I need it to instead it stacks like this. 
          [Label]
[control]
I need it to stack like this:
[label]
[control]
What am I missing? or is this just not possible with bootstrap?

```
<div class="container">   

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 text-right">
            @Html.LabelFor(d => d.EmployeeName)
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(d => d.EmployeeName, new { @class = "form-control", @autofocus = "autofocus"})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(d => d.EmployeeName)
        </div>

    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 text-right">@Html.LabelFor(d => d.EmployeeNumber)</div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(d => d.EmployeeNumber, new { @class = "form-control", @autofocus = "autofocus", style = "width:60px;" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(d => d.EmployeeNumber)
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">@Html.LabelFor(d => d.Department)</div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(d => d.Department, new { @class = "form-control", @autofocus = "autofocus", style = "width:60px;" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(d => d.Department)
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">@Html.LabelFor(d => d.DateSubmitted)</div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(d => d.DateSubmitted, new { @Value = @DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString(), @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly", style = "width:auto;" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(d => d.DateSubmitted)
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">@Html.LabelFor(d => d.DonationType)</div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 dropdown">
            @Html.DropDownList("DonationType", ViewBag.DonationType as SelectList, new { @class = "form-control"})

            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(d => d.DonationType)
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">@Html.LabelFor(d => d.Organization)</div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(d => d.Organization, new { @class = "form-control", @autofocus = "autofocus" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(d => d.Organization)
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">@Html.LabelFor(d => d.Address)</div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(d => d.Address, new { @class = "form-control", @autofocus = "autofocus" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(d => d.Address)
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 text-right">
            @Html.LabelFor(d => d.City)

        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(d => d.City, new { @class = "form-control", @autofocus = "autofocus", style = "width:50%;" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(d => d.City)
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">@Html.LabelFor(d => d.State)</div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(d => d.State, new { @class = "form-control", @autofocus = "autofocus", style = "width:25%;" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(d => d.State)
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">@Html.LabelFor(d => d.Zip)</div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(d => d.Zip, new { @class = "form-control", @autofocus = "autofocus", style = "width:25%;" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(d => d.Zip)
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">@Html.LabelFor(d => d.Category)</div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            @Html.DropDownList("Category", ViewBag.Category as SelectList, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">@Html.LabelFor(d => d.DateOfRequest)</div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(d => d.DateOfRequest, new { @class = "form-control datepicker", placeholder = "Pick a Date", style = "width:100px" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(d => d.State)
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">@Html.LabelFor(d => d.AmountRequested)</div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(d => d.AmountRequested, new { @class = "form-control", style = "width:100px" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(d => d.AmountRequested)
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">@Html.LabelFor(d => d.AccountNumber)</div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            @Html.DropDownList("AccountNumber", ViewBag.AccountNumber as SelectList, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(d => d.AccountNumber)
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">@Html.LabelFor(d => d.RequestDescription)</div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            @Html.TextAreaFor(d => d.RequestDescription, new { @class = "form-control", @autofocus = "autofocus" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(d => d.RequestDescription)
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">@Html.LabelFor(d => d.BenefitToMembers)</div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            @Html.TextAreaFor(d => d.BenefitToMembers, new { @class = "form-control", @autofocus = "autofocus" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(d => d.BenefitToMembers)
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">@Html.LabelFor(d => d.NumMembersBenefited)</div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(d => d.NumMembersBenefited, new { @class = "form-control", @autofocus = "autofocus", style = "width:35%;" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(d => d.NumMembersBenefited)
        </div>
    </div>


    <br />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-2" ;>@Html.LabelFor(d => d.RecommendedName)</div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(d => d.RecommendedName, new { @class = "form-control", @autofocus = "autofocus" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(d => d.RecommendedName)
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">@Html.LabelFor(d => d.RecommendTitle)</div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(d => d.RecommendTitle, new { @class = "form-control", @autofocus = "autofocus" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(d => d.RecommendTitle)
        </div>

    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">@Html.LabelFor(d => d.Priority)</div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            @Html.DropDownList("Priority", ViewBag.Priority as SelectList, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(d => d.Priority)
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />

</div>
```

Here is an example in just html.

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 text-right">
            <label for="employeeName">Employee Name:</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="EmployeeName" /> 
        </div>
    </div>
```

[At full screen img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mpbw3.png)

[smaller screen img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2pLQ.png)

Comment: Provide a working example (use snippets or http://jsfiddle.net to create a demo). Don't use asp.net, provide the output you got (the html).

Comment: *instead it stacks like this. [Label] [control] I need it to stack like this: [label] [control]* ??? The only difference in your description is that you didn't capitalize label the second time.

Comment: Sorry for the mix up but it didn't line everything up the way I thought it would.  I edited the question and added some more stuff.  Sorry first time using stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

I was mistaken, there actually is a built in way to do this in Bootstrap. What you want to do is use the CSS for [horizontal forms](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

The above is just the code from Bootstrap's example.

Comment: Awesome.  I tested it out and I think that is going to work for me.  I appreciate the help.